# Matching HTML with NSRegularExpression

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, regex, nsregularexpression

Basically I'm looking for a good example of matching HTML (also newlines and whitespace) using NSRegularExpression.

I have this PHP code I wrote a while back:

```
preg_match_all("/<dt>(.+?)<\/dt>\W+<dd>(.+?)<\/dd>/si",       $data, $m['deets']);
```

Now I know this works in PHP but for the life of me I can't translate it to Objective-C.  Here was my attempt.

```
NSRegularExpression *regex  = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"<dt>(.+?)<\/dt>\W+<dd>(.+?)<\/dd>" options:(NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive) error:&error];
return [regex matchesInString:target options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [target length])];
```

My target in this case is a bunch of HTML.

Comment: I hate to be 'that guy', but there's a fairly popular view round these parts that processing HTML with RegExes is a Bad Idea... it might be an idea to look for a dedicated SGML/HTML parser.

Comment: Have you tried your code with a very simple regular expression ?

Comment: I appreciate the sentiment but unfortunately the sites I'm scraping aren't using particularly good HTML (loading the DOM is rough).

Comment: Also this works.  I tried to answer my question but can't do that in the first 8 hours because I'm so n00b.



    @"<dt>(.+?)</dt>\\W+<dd>(.+?)</dd>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used NSRegularExpression, but NSPredicate instead :

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSString* pattern = @"/<dt>(.+?)<\/dt>\W+<dd>(.+?)<\/dd>/si";

NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", pattern];
if ([predicate evaluateWithObject:myTargetString] == YES) {
  // Okay
} else {
  // Not found
}
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT :**

NSPredicate is cool, be don't work if you want to get the matching range of your target string.

Your code is right, but the problem comes from the regexp expression, you must escape your \ characters and not escape / ones.

```
@"<dt>(.+?)</dt>\\W+<dd>(.+?)</dd>"
```

So :

```
NSRegularExpression *regex  = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"<dt>(.+?)</dt>\\W+<dd>(.+?)</dd>" options:(NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive) error:&error];
return [regex matchesInString:target options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [target length])];
```

Comment: Will this kick back matches?  If so how do I get them?  That's what I'm looking for.  :)

Comment: Hum... I don't think so. Yeah, that's why you use NSRegularExpression ! After seeing the doc, it seems that your code is good. I think the problem is around the regular expression itself, with the escaping caracter "\".

Comment: You're absolutely right, Martin.  This works:








    @"<dt>(.+?)</dt>\\W+<dd>(.+?)</dd>"